# QML FileDialog nameFilters case sensitive on Linux?

Tags: qt, qml

The following code will correctly display *.ext and *.EXT files on Windows and Mac. **It does NOT display *.EXT (and of course *.Ext, *.eXt, *.exT...) files on Linux.** What's my mistake?

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1

FileDialog
{
  title: "Please choose a file"
  nameFilters: [ "Scene files (*.ext)" ]
  selectMultiple: true
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Linux file system is case sensitive, and that is why it won't return *.EXT files.

The following should work:

```
nameFilters: [ "Scene files (*.ext *.EXT)" ]
```

Comment: I know this would work but it is far from a nice solution actually. 1) It displays ext and EXT to the users which is useless; 2) What now with files like *.Ext? I thought this was handled by Qt actually...

Comment: Actually, it seems that LibreOffice works that way. odt files are displayed. ODT files are not...